# Python Class Initialization Error. Cannot initialize an Imported class

Tags: python, class, initialization, call

I am trying to initialize a class `ModuleLMPC` from `commander.py` which is the main class. I get following error.

```
File "D:\CARLA\PythonAPI\examples\fnc\commander.py", line 89, in __init__
    self.LMPC = ModuleLMPC(self.dt, self.LapTime, self.maxLaps, self.Map)

TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

I import `ModuleLMPC` as:

```
from ModuleLMPC import ModuleLMPC
```

I am trying to import `ModuleLMPC` from `ModuleLMPC.py` file. They have the same name.
The `ModuleLMPC` first few lines look like:

```
from SysModel import Simulator, PID
from Classes import ClosedLoopData, LMPCprediction
from PathFollowingLTVMPC import PathFollowingLTV_MPC
from PathFollowingLTIMPC import PathFollowingLTI_MPC
from LMPC import ControllerLMPC
from Utilities import Regression
import numpy as np
import pdb
import pickle


class ModuleLMPC(object):
    def __init(self, dt, Time, maxlaps, map):
        # ======================================================================================================================
        # ============================ Choose which controller to run ==========================================================
        # ======================================================================================================================
        self.RunPID     = 1
        self.RunMPC     = 1
```

And I initialize `ModuleLMPC` in `commander.py` as:

```
self.LMPC = ModuleLMPC(self.dt, self.LapTime, self.maxLaps, self.Map)
```

I even moved everything in the same folder. Not sure what the error means.

Comment: Is it in a directory called `ModuleLMPC`? In general, you shouldn't be naming your class and module the same name anyhow, it goes against style-guidelines, where modules should use lowercase, and class names should be `CapitalCase`

Comment: What does `print(ModuleLMPC)` show you? Also, `print(ModuleLMPC.__spec__)`

Comment: I will make those changes suggested by you. Thanks. I also noticed that my `__init` is a typo. But I guess I will have few more error even if I fix that cuz of the naming. Thanks again!

Comment: Well, the naming shouldn't produce an error, but it does make things confusing. But basically, `ModuleLMPC` is a module in whatever scope you are using it. Why it's a module, well, you need to provide a [mcve] otherwise we can only guess